# Expand a dataset by two variables and count the number of existing matches

Tags: r, dataframe, grid, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
test_df <- tibble(
  category = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'),
  group = c("X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z"),
  category_data_1 = c(rep("dataA", 2), rep("dataB", 3), rep("dataC", 1)),
  category_data_2 = c(rep("data2A", 2), rep("data2B", 3), rep("data2C", 1))
  
)
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  category group category_data_1 category_data_2
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>           <chr>          
1 a        X     dataA           data2A         
2 a        Y     dataA           data2A         
3 b        Z     dataB           data2B         
4 b        X     dataB           data2B         
5 b        Y     dataB           data2B         
6 c        Z     dataC           data2C
```

I want two things to happen to this dataset:

1. Expand it by `category` and `group` (this is the easy party, e.g. `tidyr::expand()`), but leave the `category_data` variables in the dataset -- they are always tied to the `category variable`. So, `category == "a"`, will have `category_data_1 == "dataA"` and `category_data_2 == "data2A"` across the dataset.
2. I want to create a new binary variable that checks if the combination of `category` and `group` existed (`1`) or not (`0`).

So, in the end I would like something that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
  category group category_data_1 category_data_2 combination_existed
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>           <chr>                         <dbl>
1 a        X     dataA           data2A                            1
2 a        Y     dataA           data2A                            1
3 a        Z     dataA           data2A                            0
4 b        X     dataB           data2B                            1
5 b        Y     dataB           data2B                            1
6 b        Z     dataB           data2B                            1
7 c        X     dataC           data2C                            0
8 c        Y     dataC           data2C                            0
9 c        Z     dataC           data2C                            1
```

I think I can achieve this by Frankensteining several temporary datasets together, but was wondering maybe there's an easier path? Perhaps with `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple Solution, relying on `tidyr::expand` and `tidyr::nesting`.
`tidyr::nesting` can be used to prevent from new combinations of variables being created.

```
test_df %>%
  expand(nesting(category, category_data_1, category_data_2), group) %>%
  left_join(test_df %>% mutate(x = 1), by = colnames(test_df)) %>%
  replace_na(list(x = 0))

# A tibble: 9 x 5
  category category_data_1 category_data_2 group     x
  <chr>    <chr>           <chr>           <chr> <dbl>
1 a        dataA           data2A          X         1
2 a        dataA           data2A          Y         1
3 a        dataA           data2A          Z         0
4 b        dataB           data2B          X         1
5 b        dataB           data2B          Y         1
6 b        dataB           data2B          Z         1
7 c        dataC           data2C          X         0
8 c        dataC           data2C          Y         0
9 c        dataC           data2C          Z         1
```

Comment: Thanks, for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need `tidyr::complete` with its two arguments `fill` and `nesting` to do it nicely for you.  But you'll have to create a new column as desired before using `complete`.  So a complete syntax could be

```r
library(tibble)
test_df <- tibble(
  category = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'),
  group = c("X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z"),
  category_data_1 = c(rep("dataA", 2), rep("dataB", 3), rep("dataC", 1)),
  category_data_2 = c(rep("data2A", 2), rep("data2B", 3), rep("data2C", 1))
  
)

library(tidyverse)
test_df %>% mutate(combination_existed = 1) %>%
  complete(group = unique(test_df$group), nesting(category, category_data_1, category_data_2), 
           fill = list(combination_existed = 0))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>   group category category_data_1 category_data_2 combination_existed
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>           <chr>                         <dbl>
#> 1 X     a        dataA           data2A                            1
#> 2 X     b        dataB           data2B                            1
#> 3 X     c        dataC           data2C                            0
#> 4 Y     a        dataA           data2A                            1
#> 5 Y     b        dataB           data2B                            1
#> 6 Y     c        dataC           data2C                            0
#> 7 Z     a        dataA           data2A                            0
#> 8 Z     b        dataB           data2B                            1
#> 9 Z     c        dataC           data2C                            1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

or writing this a bit differently, to get an output as required

- taking out `category` from `nesting` and adding a group_by on it.  There is no difference in both syntaxes but, group_by on `category` causes it to place earlier than other columns, which is as per expected output.

```
test_df %>% mutate(combination_existed = 1) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  complete(group = unique(test_df$group), nesting(category_data_1, category_data_2), 
           fill = list(combination_existed = 0))

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   category [3]
  category group category_data_1 category_data_2 combination_existed
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>           <chr>                         <dbl>
1 a        X     dataA           data2A                            1
2 a        Y     dataA           data2A                            1
3 a        Z     dataA           data2A                            0
4 b        X     dataB           data2B                            1
5 b        Y     dataB           data2B                            1
6 b        Z     dataB           data2B                            1
7 c        X     dataC           data2C                            0
8 c        Y     dataC           data2C                            0
9 c        Z     dataC           data2C                            1
```

Comment: Thanks, for the quick answer!

Comment: Glad to have been of help.  :)